# Creating interactive animations of physical systems in Python

Tags: python, reference, matplotlib, plot, interactive

I am currently diving into Python, coming from Mathematica/Matlab/C. I want to learn how to create **interactive plots** (or better *animations*) in Python's [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) library and possibly integrate them into GUIs, using Tkinter or PyQt. There are good examples on the web that show end results, for instance [this one](http://hardsoftlucid.wordpress.com/various-stuff/realtime-plotting/#respond).

My **question** is, however: is there any **well-structured tutorial** or **book** available to learn this (i.e. creating interactive animations in python) from the ground up?

I'm an intermediate in Python, and beginner in Tkinter. I have googled this (of course), so I get pieces of the puzzle but not the entire picture.

Answer (score 2):

Jake Vanderplas has some wonderful animation examples in his blog, and in my opinion they're thouroughly explained (some familiarity with matplotlib needed):

- [An interactive minesweeper](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/12/06/minesweeper-in-matplotlib/)
- [An interactive (3D) Rubik's cube](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/11/26/3d-interactive-rubiks-cube-in-python/). This might seem intimidating, but you'll see that he links to a previous post where the building *cubes* are explained.
- [A tutorial on matplotlib animations](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), though not about *interactive* plots.

Integrating a plot in a Qt (or Tk) application shouldn't be very difficult, but I am not aware of any good tutorial. An example that I found useful (you may have already seen it) is [this one](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/20/matplotlib-with-pyqt-guis/).